# TableView Repeating youtube-api result

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, youtube-api

The problem is---->
The TableView Display the same title and Distribution in all cells

my project ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    var articles: [Article]? = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchArticles()
    }

    func fetchArticles(){
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=horses&type=video&maxResults=10&key=(apiKey)")!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error as Any)
                return
            }

            self.articles = [Article]()
            do {
                let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? [String : Any]
                let article = Article()
                if let articlesFromJson = json?["items"] as? [[String : Any]] {
                    for item in articlesFromJson {


                        if let snippet = item["snippet"] as? [String : Any],let title = snippet["title"]as? String,let desc = snippet["description"]as? String {
                             article.headline = title
                             article.desc = desc
                            self.articles?.append(article)
                        }
                    }
                  }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableview.reloadData()

                }    
            }        
        }
 task.resume()   
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleCell", for: indexPath) as? ArticleCell

        cell?.title.text = self.articles?[indexPath.row].headline!
        cell?.desc.text = self.articles?[indexPath.row].desc!

        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.articles?.count ?? 0
    }

}
```

**Article.Swift :**

```
import UIKit

class Article: NSObject {

    var headline: String?
    var desc: String?
}

**ArticleCell :**

import UIKit

class ArticleCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var desc: UILabel!



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

The problem is---->
The TableView Display the same title and Distribution in all cells

Comment: have you checked array content? Are they same or different?

Comment: they are different :/

Comment: in cellforrow method , print(articles) and confirm it is same or not!

Comment: Can you share the articles data that you fetched?

Comment: when I'm trying to print articles the result is.    [<newsReader.Article: 0x1702848d0>]
[<newsReader.Article: 0x1702848d0>, <newsReader.Article: 0x1702848d0>]
[<newsReader.Article: 0x1702848d0>, <newsReader.Article: 0x1702848d0>, <newsReader.Article: 0x1702848d0>]
[<newsReader.Article: 0x1702848d0>, <newsReader.Article: 0x1702848d0>, <newsReader.Article: 0x1702848d0>, <newsReader.Article: 0x1702848d0>]
[<newsReader.Article: 0x1702848d0>, <newsReader.Article: 0x1702848d0>,

Comment: but when print article.desc it display the right info

Comment: yes  insert   let article = Article()  inside  for loop check update

Comment: you solve it man thanxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just comment this line

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableview.reloadData()

            }
```

/*and add it after for loop

   insert `let article = Article()`  inside  for loop*/

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    var articles: [Article]? = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchArticles()
    }

    func fetchArticles(){
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=horses&type=video&maxResults=10&key=(apiKey)")!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error as Any)
                return
            }

            self.articles = [Article]()
            do {
                let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? [String : Any]

                if let articlesFromJson = json?["items"] as? [[String : Any]] {
                    for item in articlesFromJson {


                        if let snippet = item["snippet"] as? [String : Any],let title = snippet["title"]as? String,let desc = snippet["description"]as? String {
                           let article = Article()
                             article.headline = title
                             article.desc = desc
                            self.articles?.append(article)
                        }
                    }

                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                  }

                /*DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableview.reloadData()

                }  */

            }        
        }
 task.resume()   
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleCell", for: indexPath) as? ArticleCell

        cell?.title.text = self.articles?[indexPath.row].headline!
        cell?.desc.text = self.articles?[indexPath.row].desc!

        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.articles?.count ?? 0
    }

}
```

Comment: its the same :/

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleCell", for: indexPath) as? ArticleCell

        cell?.title.text = self.articles?[indexPath.row].headline!
        cell?.desc.text = self.articles?[indexPath.row].desc!

        return cell!
    }